# Where to ask a question about fishing?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a StackExchange site appropriate to ask a question regarding the viability of a certain kind of bait for fishing, or would that have to fall under Area 51?

Comment: For phishing, you could try https://security.stackexchange.com/ . :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd check on [Outdoors.SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

They have a bunch of [questions](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fishing) about fishing and even about bait specifically.